# Update Database to match array (Many to Many)

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have 3 tables, lets call them Table1, Table2 and ManyMany table.

```
Table 1: 
ID1 [PK],
Description1

Table 2: 
ID2 [PK],
Description2

ManyMany:
ID1 [PK, FK],
ID2 [PK, FK]
```

I have 2 arrays:

Both of them use a PK from Table1 (ID1 == 3) and contain ID2 values.

```
Array1 [5,6,8]     // from DB 
Array2 [5,6,9]     // from front-end
```

What I want to do is compare the 2 arrays and update the ManyMany to match Array2. So in this case record 'ID1 == 3 && ID2 == 8' must be deleted and record 'ID1 == 3 && ID2 == 9' must be added. But this will change. Can be multiple deletes and inserts etc..

How can I update the DB to match array2?
Are there a easy way to accomplish this?
It will be quite inefficient to delete all the records matching ID1 and inserting them again.

I am using ASP.NET Web API with LINQ and EntityFramework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem using Linq's Except() extensions:

```
var toRemove = array1.Except(array2)
foreach(var item in toRemove) {
    array1.Remove(item);
}
var toAdd = array2.Except(array1)
foreach(var item in toAdd) {
    array1.Add(item);
}

//Do whatever you need to persist to the DB...
```